# Traceback error Python

Tags: python, traceback

I am getting a traceback error on a script code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "D:\Working\ToolShare\Scripts\SML.py", line 121, in &lt;module> fieldmappings.addTable(input)
File "c:\program files(x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\arcobjects.py", line 313, in addTable
return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.AddTable(*gp_fixargs(args)))
RuntimeError: FieldMappings: Error in adding table to field mappings

Line 313 says: #arcpy.AddField_management(currentPath +"\\Gravel_Areas.dbf", "EFFDATE", "DATE", "", "", "", "EFFDATE", "", "", "")
```

I didn't create the script but altered it to change the type of what I am comparing between two data sets. The process should join a table and created new fields and compared area, ownership and anything new, and spit out separate DBF files.
With the original script tool, the process is fine and has no issues with the process. The only thing was changed was the name of the type I am interested in.

Comment: Well, have you compared what is different between your input and the input that worked? You haven't given us enough information to figure it out.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).